# How can I get progress bar to increment by one block till end of bar? Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

How I could get a progress bar to increment by one block each time the correct button is clicked, till eventually the progress bar is filled. I have tried, but didn't work, so thought I would ask on here for guidance on how to achieve this or go about this.

Not worked much with progress bars and not worried about maximum values at the moment or minimum, if that is any help.

Hope I have explained my problem with enough detail and any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: ProgressBar hasn't displayed "blocks" in a very long time.  Are you working on some kind of ancient machine?  The size of the block doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question i have created a sample. Please try this will some times helps you. Please share your code. So that we can help more

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 10; // Maximum should be based on your value
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a while to reply. I figured something out, which works how I wanted it. I know you shouldn't use this space to say thank you, but appreciate the help - put me on the right tracks!